# How do I stop the New Relic server monitor without a tonne of alerts?

Tags: newrelic

We spin up new servers to replace existing servers a LOT and I don't like the white noise of server alerts every time we do that. I don't want people to ignore the real alerts when a live server is malfunctioning.

Is there a way to stop the New Relic server monitor in a graceful way that won't throw warnings and alerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the alerts tab in Servers, then choose Server Policies from the left-hand column, you should see all the policies set up for Servers on your account. You can then disable the policies you're worried about firing before you stop the Server monitor. Re-enable it when you're ready. This should help with your problem

Cheers,
Fidelicatessen
New Relic Technical Support Engineer

Comment: Thanks! I created a "Decommissioned Server Policy" with no Downtime alert and I disabled all of the alerts within the policy. I will apply this policy to the servers we're removing before we start the decommission process.